# replace multiple string in array if the not satisfied the condition using php

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have trouble to find the multiple string and replace it with the new string within an array.

this is my array

```html
array (0) = <mfenced><mfrac><mrow><mn>2</mn><mi>x</mi><mo>+</mo><mn>3</mn></mrow><mi>x</mi></mfrac></mfenced>
array (1) = <mfenced><mrow><mn>2</mn><mi>x</mi><mo>+</mo><mn>3</mn></mrow></mfenced>
```

I need to find `<mrow>` and look for the next tag, if the next tag is `<mo>` then I no need to anything, else I need to add `<mo>+</mo>` next to it.

for example

```html
array (0) = <mfenced><mfrac><mrow><mo>+</mo><mn>2</mn><mi>x</mi><mo>+</mo><mn>3</mn></mrow><mi>x</mi></mfrac></mfenced>
array (1) = <mfenced><mrow><mo>+</mo><mn>2</mn><mi>x</mi><mo>+</mo><mn>3</mn></mrow></mfenced>
```

this is my current code

```html
$res1=array();
$temp = [];
for ($i=0; $i <count($addplus) ; $i++) { 
    $res1 = $addplus[$i];
     while($pos = strpos($res1, "<mrow>",1))
    {
        if ($pos1=substr($res1,$pos,$pos + 4) != "<mo>")
        {
            $temp=str_replace($pos, "<mrow><mo>+</mo>", $res1);
        }
        else 
        {
            $temp= $res1;
        }         
    }
}
print_r($temp);
```

$addplus store the array. thank you in advance, have a nice day!

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:javascript]?

Comment: Seems like might be easier with an xml parser rather than parsing strings

Comment: or a preg_replace with a lookbehind.

Comment: @Luca sorry my bad,stackoverflow suggested the tag

Comment: @charlietfl im not familiar with xml . can you teach me?

Comment: @Jeff i will figured it

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

Comment: So what is your problem?

Comment: @SaeedBolhasani the code not produce the result i want it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
foreach ($addplus as $key => $string) {
    $t = explode("<mrow>", $string);
    if(substr($t[1], 0, 4) != '<mo>') {
      $addplus[$key] = $t[0].'<mrow><mo>+</mo>'.$t[1];
    }
}
```

"what if string in array ?i mean  appear more than one time"

```
foreach ($addplus as $key => $string) {
    $t = explode("<mrow>", $string);
    $final = "";
    for($i = 1; $i < count($t); ++$i) {
      if(substr($t[$i], 0, 4) != '<mo>') {
        $final = $final.$t[$i-1].'<mrow><mo>+</mo>'.$t[$i];
      }
      else {
        $final = $final.'<mrow>'.$t[$i];
      }
    }
    $addplus[$key] = $final;
}
```

Comment: @fismong3r what if string in array ?i mean <mrow> appear more than one time

Comment: @jaiwilshere Updated my answer. Had no time to test tough, but you understand the point.